# Hurst exponent of stock using R/S analysis

Tags: time-series, stationarity, hurst-exponent

I am attempting to use R/S analysis to estimate the Hurst Exponent on a single stock.

At first I directly use the stock price ( instead of stock return) and the Hurst component calculated is > 0.9 ( used Apple, Google respectively from 2010 to 2017) which seems to be incorrect.

Then I tried to use log return(daily) instead and the result is around 0.5 which seems normal.

So I should use return instead of stocks price but why?
Is this related to stationarity of the time series?( I believe stock price is clearly non-stationary and return is stationary)

Thanks.